# Is there a straightforward way, with Apex to determine the creation order of a given Object's child records (i.e. which was created first?)?

Tags: apex

Hoping to avail myself of the great minds in this group...

I am creating code that syncs two custom fields. One of these fields is on `Opportunity` and the other is on `Contact`.

The sync will happen by way of an `OpportunityContactRole` record, such that the custom field on a given `Opportunity` record will have its value set to the value of the field on the `Contact` for whichever of the Opportunity's `OpportunityContactRole` records is flagged with `IsPrimary`.

I can accomplish this in a fairly straightforward way, for example, like:

```
List<OpportunityContactRole> contactRoles = new List<OpportunityContactRole>();
List<Opportunity> opportunitiesToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();

contactRoles = ([
    SELECT 
        OpportunityId, 
        Contact.Custom_Field__c, 
        IsPrimary 
            FROM 
            OpportunityContactRole
                WHERE 
                Condition 1 AND Condition 2]);

for(OpportunityContactRole ocr : contactRoles) {
    Opportunity opportunity = new Opportunity(Id = ocr.OpportunityId);
    if(ocr.IsPrimary == true) {
        opportunity.Custom_Field__c = ocr.Contact.Custom_Field__c;
        opportunitiesToUpdate.add(opportunity);
    }
}

update opportunitiesToUpdate;
```

The problem I have been struggling with for two days, however, is the additional requirement I've been given, which states:

- In the event no `OpportunityContactRole` record for a given opportunity has been designated as `IsPrimary`, then the `OpportunityContactRole` record that was created *first* should be used as if it were `IsPrimary`.

I have no idea how to do this. Can anyone get me started in the right direction? Do I need to build some sort of helper to process time between `System.now()` and a record's `CreatedDate`?

Maybe the answer is right in front of me, but I have done a lot of searching and am still stuck. Please let me know if I can provide any more background or other information, or if I can ask this question in a better way.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Why not just `ORDER BY CreatedDate`? Then the first element is the earliest one.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed! What is the best way to go about processing the non-```IsPrimary```records? Given the query result that I'm iterating over from my example above (contactRoles) and the 1:M relationship between `Opportunity` and ```OpportunityContactRole```, if, say, half of the records were ```IsPrimary```, I'd now have to avoid updating the `Opportunity` records that other non-`IsPrimary` child records may share as a parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As David has suggested, ordering by CreatedDate should be the key to solving this issue. Once you've done that there are multiple ways to solve the problem but this is the clearest one for me:

```
List<OpportunityContactRole> contactRoles = new List<OpportunityContactRole>();
List<Opportunity> opportunitiesToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
Set<Id> opportunitiesWithPriorityContact = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> updatedOpportunities = new Set<Id>();

// Order by CreatedDate so the first in the list is the first created
contactRoles = ([
    SELECT OpportunityId, 
           Contact.Custom_Field__c, 
           IsPrimary 
    FROM OpportunityContactRole
    WHERE Condition 1 AND 
          Condition 2
    ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC
]);

for(OpportunityContactRole ocr : contactRoles) {
    if(ocr.IsPrimary == true) {
        opportunitiesWithPriorityContact.add(ocr.OpportunityId);
    }
}

for(OpportunityContactRole ocr : contactRoles) {
    Opportunity opportunity = new Opportunity(Id = ocr.OpportunityId);
    Boolean validRecord = false;

    // only update if it hasn't been updated before
    if(!updatedOpportunities.contains(ocr.OpportunityId)) {
        // search for primary only if the opportunity has at least one
        if(opportunitiesWithPriorityContact.contains(ocr.OpportunityId)) {
            if(ocr.IsPrimary == true) {
                validRecord = true;
            }
        // if there is no primary then use the first it finds in the loop
        } else {
            validRecord = true;
        }
    }

    // using a boolean to prevent duplicate code
    if(validRecord) {
        opportunity.Custom_Field__c = ocr.Contact.Custom_Field__c;
        opportunitiesToUpdate.add(opportunity);
        updatedOpportunities.add(ocr.OpportunityId);
    }
}

update opportunitiesToUpdate;
```

Let me know how you get on.

Edit: changed from using list.contains opportunitiesToUpdate to using a seperate set

Comment: +1, nice solution. I think you're going to run into trouble with `List.contains()`, though. At the point where you add the value to `opportunitiesToUpdate`, it has the custom field set, but at the point where you check membership, it does not, which will produce incorrect results. I think you'll want a `Map<Id, Opportunity>` instead.

Comment: @David, Yes, good point, my first draft used an additional set but thought I could remove. I'll update to include it back in.

Comment: I was able to get this implemented and working perfectly. I deployed last night. Thank you, to both yourself and @DavidReed. I will update the question to include this additional requirement of ensuring opportunities with `IsPrimary` records aren't overwritten with values from other sibling, non-`IsPrimary` records. Cheers!